# "Du bist gemein" — what is its meaning in English?

Tags: german-to-english

*Du bist gemein* or *das ist gemein*.

What does a native German speaker really mean by that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main context is "you are mean" or "that's cruel".

Basic translations: http://www.dict.cc/?s=gemein

Comment: "Mean" in the meaning of "nasty", not "tight with money".

Answer (score 5):

As [already pointed out](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/du-bist-gemein-what-is-its-meaning-in-english/2775#2775) the colloquial meaning of *"Du bist gemein"* is *"You are mean"* but depending on face expression it can also be used as *"Don't be so mean"*.

Likewise, other meanings of *"gemein"* very much depend on context, best seen in the incredible long list of synonyms [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gemein) offers:

> <sup>auffallend, aufs Äußerste, ausgemacht, ausgesprochen, ausgesucht, außergewöhnlich, außerordentlich, äußerst, beachtlich, bedeutend, bemerkenswert, besonders, bitter, bitterlich, brennend, denkbar, empfindlich, erstaunlich, extrem, ganz, gehörig, grenzenlos, hell, hellauf, herzlich, hoch, höchst, hoffnungslos, in hohem Maße, leidenschaftlich, maßlos, peinlich, tief, übermäßig, unanständig, unaussprechlich, unbändig, unbeschreiblich, unerträglich, ungemein, ungewöhnlich, unmäßig, unsagbar, unübersehbar, unvergleichlich; (gehoben) abgründig, auserlesen, ausnehmend, namenlos, überaus, über die/alle Maßen, unermesslich, unsäglich, zuinnerst; (bildungssprachlich) eminent, infernalisch; (umgangssprachlich) abscheulich, bestialisch, böse, bullig, dick, ekelhaft, eklig, elend, enorm, entsetzlich, fabelhaft, furchtbar, fürchterlich, gewaltig, grässlich, grauenhaft, grauenvoll, gräulich, grausam, grausig, gründlich, himmlisch, höllisch, hübsch, knallig, königlich, mächtig, mörderisch, nett, niederträchtig, ordentlich, rasend, reichlich, rettungslos, riesig, schandbar, schändlich, schlimm, schrecklich, sündhaft, teuflisch, toll, total, tüchtig, unglaublich, unheimlich, unsinnig, unsterblich, unwahrscheinlich, verdammt, verflixt, verrückt, voll, wahnsinnig, wunderbar, wundervoll; (salopp) brutal, gottserbärmlich, hundserbärmlich, hundsmäßig, irre, irrsinnig, tierisch, verflucht; (emotional) abgöttisch, barbarisch, erbärmlich, haushoch, jämmerlich, märchenhaft, unendlich, unvorstellbar, verzweifelt, zutiefst; (oft emotional übertreibend) tödlich, unerhört, ungeheuer, ungeheuerlich; (umgangssprachlich emotional) kolossal, sagenhaft, scheußlich, unverschämt, verteufelt; (umgangssprachlich emotional verstärkend) mordsmäßig, unmenschlich; (salopp emotional verstärkend) säuisch; (scherzhaft) kannibalisch; (abwertend) lächerlich, widerlich; (umgangssprachlich abwertend) biestig, infam, schauderhaft, schauerlich; (norddeutsch) bannig; (süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch) gar; (süddeutsch, österreichisch umgangssprachlich) damisch; (süddeutsch salopp) sakrisch; (landschaftlich) aasig, arg; (veraltend) rechtschaffen, weidlich
>
>   abscheuerregend, abscheulich, abstoßend, brutal, ekelhaft, grässlich, roh, unangenehm, widerwärtig; (gehoben) degoutant; (umgangssprachlich) fies; (oft umgangssprachlich übertreibend) schaurig; (abwertend) widerlich, wüst; (besonders bayrisch, österreichisch umgangssprachlich) grauslich; (veraltet) abominabel
>
>   bösartig, böse, boshaft, garstig, hässlich, hundsgemein, lumpig, niederträchtig, schandbar, schändlich; (gehoben) frevelhaft, perfide, ruchlos, schimpflich, schmählich, übel, verachtenswert, verwerflich; (umgangssprachlich) fies; (emotional) miserabel; (abwertend) gehässig, infam, schäbig, schuftig, schurkisch; (gehoben abwertend) nichtswürdig, schnöde; (umgangssprachlich abwertend) schofel; (gehoben veraltend) verrucht; (besonders Rechtssprache) böswillig
>
>   dreist, frech, schamlos, unerhört, unverfroren, unverschämt; (landschaftlich) ausverschämt
>
>   unanständig, unfein, ungehörig; (gehoben) ungebührlich; (abwertend) schmutzig, ungehobelt; (meist abwertend) ordinär; (gehoben abwertend) unflätig; (bildungssprachlich abwertend) vulgär; (salopp abwertend) dreckig
>
>   ärgerlich, unfair, ungerecht; (umgangssprachlich abwertend) schofel; (Jugendsprache) ätzend</sup>

Comment: Indeed, an incredible long ist. But I wonder how the Duden people brought it up. To me, the first section (until _weidlich_) rather looks like a list of synonyms to _**un**gemein_.